# Robot Framework - Jupyterlab Robot Kernel Status Always Disconnected

Tags: python, robotframework, jupyter-lab

I have setup Robot Framework using Anaconda Navigator and opened jupyterlab in my local computer, unfortunately the Robot Kernel status is always on "Disconnected". I have already made sure to pip install the necessary packages (ie. robotframework, robotkernel)

I have also already did the following

- Made sure python is the correct version for robot framework
- Made sure Robot Kernel is installed
- Made sure environment paths are already configured in user environments
- Creating new environment in Anaconda that has all the necessary pre-requisites
- Restarted jupyterlab, anaconda and even the whole computer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the latest version of robotframework is causing the issue.
Try it with this:

```
pip install robotframework==6.0.2
```

(It worked for me.)